# Filter out entire records SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables: TableA and TableB

TableA Has 10 records while TableB has 8 Records.

I am trying to filter the distinct records on table B from TableA so I can then move the discrepancy to TableB.

This is a Legacy, poorly made, Database, so there is no Unique Identifiers. So they look something like this.

```
    TableA                               TableB
    Col1, Col2, Col3                Col1,Col2,Col3
 1    X     X    Y                    X    X   Y
 2    X     Y    Y                    X    Y   Y
 3    X     X    X
```

I want to filter the combination of values for each record on TableB to find the missing values that are present on TableA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a left join from tablea to tableb and get only the rows of tablea that do not match:

```
select a.*
from tablea a left join tableb b
on b.col1 = a.col1 and b.col2 = a.col2 and b.col3 = a.col3
where b.col1 is null and b.col2 is null and b.col3 is null
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this if it is on different databases? Or do I need to put them in a temporary DB to be able to do this at all?

Comment: You must qualify the table names with the database and schema names like: `from database1.dbo.tablea a left join database2.dbo.tableb b` and the 2 databases must be in the same server.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT EXIST`

```
select * 
from tablea ta 
where NOT EXIST (
     select 1 
      from tableb tb 
     where ta.col1 = tb.col1
          and ta.col2 = tb.col2
          and ta.col3 = tb.col3)
```